# How to Resolve JBOSS deployment Error : Packages waiting for a deployer?

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, jboss5.x, jboss-3.x

I have a web application is running in JBOSS 3.2.6 and built on java 1.5
In lib directory, I have placed a new jar with that jar I want to deploy my application but its showing deployment error, While I am able to build my application successfully.

Here you can check logs, can any one suggest me solution...

```
ERROR [URLDeploymentScanner] Incomplete Deployment listing:
Packages waiting for a deployer:
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@827ffe9 { 
url=file:/factoryduq/dev/fe/jboss- 
3.2.6/server/MITReportFactory/tmp/deploy/tmp48184MITReportFactory- 
1.0.0.ear-contents/nttx-ds-api-util-1.0.8.jar }
deployer: null
status: Starting
state: START_SUBDEPLOYMENTS
watch: file:/factoryduq/dev/fe/jboss- 
3.2.6/server/MITReportFactory/tmp/deploy/tmp48184MITReportFactory- 
1.0.0.ear-contents/nttx-ds-api-util-1.0.8.jar
mbeans:
```

I have already tried a method to include new jar "nttx-ds-api-util-1.0.8.jar" to place in default directory of jboss, also gave dependencies in build.xml and Application.xml

Comment: if anyone knows about this, ping me please.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is likely that JBoss has some garbage from previous deployment and has the solution not trivial but simple: Verify if your jar matches the JBoss lib folders, copy entire project jar files into Jboss lib folder if doest not match.
Then restarts JBoss.

Verify also if your file are correctly placed on the server directory and if JBOSS variable is set. [A similar issue can be found here.](https://coderanch.com/t/91368/application-servers/Incompletely-Deployed-Packages-jboss)

### Highlights

~ Please consider using at least JBoss 6.x, cause JBoss 3.x is very outdated, I would say extremely outdated and out of support.